# Array's of promises pending not sure how to handle

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have tried the usual Promise.all but I get a circular Json error. I have the following promises in my console

```
all [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]
all [ Promise { <pending> } ]
all [ Promise { <pending> } ]
all [ Promise { <pending> } ]
```

With the following code

```
const needle = require("needle");

const token = process.env.BEARER_TOKEN_TWITTER;

const endpointUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent";

export default async function login(req, res) {
  try {
    

    const all = req.body.map((item) => {
      const params = {
        query: `"$${item.title}" from:${item.twitter}`,
      };

      return needle("get", endpointUrl, params, {
        headers: {
          "User-Agent": "v2FullArchiveJS",
          authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.warn(err);
      });
    });


    console.log("all", all);
    // Update
    console.log("allll", await Promise.all(all));


    const result = await Promise.all(all);

    res.status(200).json({ authenticated: true, result: result });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
}
```

I have read the following with no luck

[How to do promise.all for array of array of promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094865/how-to-do-promise-all-for-array-of-array-of-promises)

Front End Call

```
const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = newArray.map(
        async (question) => {
          console.log("question", question.data);
          return await fetchTweets(question.data);
        }
      );

      console.log("response", response);


      
      const promise4all = await Promise.all(
        response
        );
        console.log("promise4all", promise4all);
      // setTweets(await Promise.all(response));
    };
```

[image]

Comment: it's quite large but I get about 4 of these, which usually I can just get the body but when I try to access the body I get undefined I am not sure how I got the ciruclar Json actually I deleted what I did there Here is what needle returns tho https://gist.github.com/anderskitson/8e656a0d80d924dd3f3cd06250e6688c

Comment: or actually, you can `const result = await Promise.all(all);` ... then use `result` for res.json rather than `all`

Comment: `"here is what needle returns"` ... no, it returns a Promise - read the documentation - you have to deal with promises using .then or await in your case

Comment: yeah I had done that and you see the output I get above

Comment: no I don't ... you console.log of all does NOT mean you've `await Promise.all(all)` at all ... `all` remains unchanged, it's the result of awaiting it that you need ... the code you've written does not use Promise.all so don't say you've done that since you have not

Comment: `console.log("allll", await Promise.all(all));` this returns what is in the gist, but I can't access the body if it

Comment: I've told you how .... `const result = await Promise.all(all)` ... then use `result` ... **not `all`** - `all` is an array of promises ... it never changes ... `Promise.all(all)` doesn't change `all`

Comment: You could also do `res.status(200).json({ authenticated: true, result: await Promise.all(all) });` - if you want the values, await the promises that resolve them - every time (or once and store results in a variable like my first suggestion) - awaiting a variable that is a promise does not change the variable from a promise to a resolved value - awaiting returns the resolved value

Comment: I added the code changes, but I still get this circular json because whatever is getting passed to front end is still 4 promises they never get resolved, I don't quite understand what is going on

Comment: then you're doing it wrong

Comment: suddenly it's the front end with the error? what data does `fetchTweets` return

Comment: it's not suddenly, it's been both the whole time fetchTweets return 4 promises. Anyways I got to sleep, thanks for your help. I'll figure it out in the morning

Comment: oh, but this is new code (fetchData), I thought it was the old code (login) that had the issue - what is `fetchTweets` function and what does it do

Comment: Don't swallow the needle error. Either delete the `.catch()` clause or rethrow after logging.

Answer (score 0):

Had to do the following

```
const needle = require("needle");

const token = process.env.BEARER_TOKEN_TWITTER;

const endpointUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent";

export default async function login(req, res) {
  try {
    const all = req.body.map((item) => {
      const params = {
        query: `"$${item.title}" from:${item.twitter}`,
      };

      return needle("get", endpointUrl, params, {
        headers: {
          "User-Agent": "v2FullArchiveJS",
          authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }).then(function (response) {
        return response.body;
      });
    });


    const result = Promise.all(all);


    res.status(200).json({ authenticated: true, result: await result });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
}
```

front end

```
useEffect(() => {
    // declare the async data fetching function
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = newArray.map(
        async (question) => {
          console.log("question", question.data);
          return await fetchTweets(question.data);
        }
      );

      setTweets(await Promise.all(response));
    };

    if (data) {
      fetchData();
    }

  }, [data]);
```