# How to get data from an array of requests?

Tags: javascript, http

I have an array of accounts and there are two request one is to get domain and from that get data of account. if i have to get all accounts data how can i do it?

```
accountsData = acounts.map(account => {
   getDomain(account).then(domain => getData(domain))
})

Promises.all(accountsData).then(e => console.log(e))
```

Since the few request all failing so this is not working.

I have tried the above aproch and it not works when few request fails.

Comment: Have you tried [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)  ?

Comment: Yes that does not work also.

Comment: also as i am using es2015 so i don't think this will run.

Comment: see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094865/how-to-do-promise-all-for-array-of-array-of-promises

Comment: You're not returning anything from your `map` callback.

Comment: My promise array look like this.
[Promise, Promise, Promise]
0: Promise
_U: 1
_V: 1
_W: some data
_X: null

1: Promise
_U: 1
_V: 1
_W: Error: bad resp
_X: null

Comment: @SayrasJain You can make use of Promise.allSettled for this. My answer below may help you learn more about how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Promise.allSettled

Use Promise.allSettled to check if the promise is fulfilled or rejected.

You can push the promises into an array and use Promise.allSettled on the promise array.

#### Solution

```
    for (const account of accounts) {
       getDomainPromises.push(getDomain(account));
    }
     await Promise.allSettled(getDomainPromises).then((getDominResults) =>
        getDominResults.forEach((getDomainResult) => {
          if (getDomainResult.status === 'fulfilled'){
            console.log("GD - " + getDomainResult.status, getDomainResult.value);
            getDataPromises.push(getData(getDomainResult.value))
          } else {    // status = 'rejected'
            console.log("GD - " + getDomainResult.status);
          }
        })
      );

      await Promise.allSettled(getDataPromises).then((getDataResults) =>
        getDataResults.forEach((getDataResult) => {
          
          if (getDataResult.status === 'fulfilled'){
            console.log("getData - ", getDataResult.value)
          } else {    // status = 'rejected'
            console.log("getData - REJECTED");
          }
        })
      );
```

#### Working Demo:

```js
//    Mocking getDomain Promise
function getDomain(a) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (a % 2 === 0) {
      setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'RESOLVE - getDomain - ' + a);
    } else {
      setTimeout(reject, 100, 'REJECTED - getDomain - ' + a);
    }
  })
}
//    Mocking getData Promise
function getData(a) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (Math.round(Math.random()*100) % 2 === 0) {
      setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'RESOLVE - getData - ' + a);
    } else {
      setTimeout(reject, 100, 'REJECTED - getData - ' + a);
    }
  })
}

// SOLUTION::
const accounts = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const getDomainPromises = [];
const getDataPromises = [];
for (const account of accounts) {
  getDomainPromises.push(getDomain(account));
}

async function run() {
  await Promise.allSettled(getDomainPromises).then((getDominResults) =>
    getDominResults.forEach((getDomainResult) => {
      if (getDomainResult.status === 'fulfilled'){
        console.log("GD - " + getDomainResult.status, getDomainResult.value);
        getDataPromises.push(getData(getDomainResult.value))
      } else {    // status = 'rejected'
        console.log("GD - " + getDomainResult.status);
      }
    })
  );

  await Promise.allSettled(getDataPromises).then((getDataResults) =>
    getDataResults.forEach((getDataResult) => {
      
      if (getDataResult.status === 'fulfilled'){
        console.log("getData - ", getDataResult.value)
      } else {    // status = 'rejected'
        console.log("getData - REJECTED");
      }
    })
  );
}

run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a `Promise` on each iteration of the map

```
accountsData = acounts.map(account => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      getDomain(account)
          .then(domain => getData(domain)
              .then(data => resolve(data)))
  });
})
// e would be of the format [data1, data2, .....]
Promises.all(accountsData).then(e => console.log(e))
```

Comment: You don't need to create and return an explicit new Promise, since `getDomain()` is itself a Promise. So just `return getDomain(account).then(getData);` should suffice